# Star rating with css - how to align text value with icons, so that they are the same height and size

Tags: html, css, icons, rating

I need to create a star rating and I want it to look exactly as on the image ([image]). I used google icon for stars and and  for numeric value. However, I don't know how to align this value with icons so that the would be on the same line. For now "(50%)" are slightly below the baseline of star icons. I tried to display numeric value as a block and give to it margins and paddings, but this didn't help.

Here's my HTML by now:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<i class="material-icons">star</i>
<i class="material-icons">star</i>
<i class="material-icons">star</i>
<i class="material-icons">star</i>
<i class="material-icons">star_border</i>
<span id="rating">(50%)</span>
```

Any help or trick-suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Can I see more HTML code and CSS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the icons are automatically aligned to the top. So if you use `vertical-align: bottom;` they will then have the same baseline as the text.

```css
.star-wrapper i {
 vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="star-wrapper">
<i class="material-icons">star</i>
<i class="material-icons">star</i>
<i class="material-icons">star</i>
<i class="material-icons">star</i>
<i class="material-icons">star_border</i>
<span id="rating">(50%)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you and for explaining what was the problem too